# NOC TVs needing to automatically login for monitoring website

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Background: NOC (Network Operation Center) TVs have raspberry pi with raspbian connected.
Issue: Website will not login automatically.
Goal: Raspberry pi boot, open chromium, open website, credentials inserted automatically, and Login.

I was able to resolve the majority of the issues except for the website auto-login.

config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
    @/usr/bin/chromium-browser --incognito --start-maximized --kiosk                        https://solarwinds.com
    @unclutter
    @xset s off
    @xset s noblank
    @xset -dpms

This issue isn't specifically to raspbian but that is the OS I'm needing the solution for.

Answer (score 0):

A login Python script resolved this issue, selenium-IDE was able to record actions and make it a script. It was very handy.

Comment: This answer provides very little information. Could you explain in more detail how this answers the issue presented in the question? Maybe even describe the steps you took or the code you used?